# JSON to SVG plan drawing with D3js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

So this will be the first time where I couldn't find an answer to my problem just by searching..

I am quite new to D3 and to Javascript in general, and what I am trying to achieve is a visualisation of some curves exported from a CAD tool (Autodesk Revit) in my browser. I have exported the geometry to json, and the data structure can be reviewed here: http://codepen.io/MadsHolten/pen/RaJGOp.js

As you can see I have lines and arcs. For now I am just trying to get the lines to work, but I haven't succeeded yet.

My approach is to loop through the data and generate a new Javascript object in the following format:

`[ [{x: startX, y: startY},{x: endX, y: endY}],[{...},{...}] ]`

I thought I had succeeded, but I recieve the following error: 
"Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN""

There might be a problem with the data type of the coordinates (but I can't see why).

```
var w = 1000,
h = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
 .attr("width", w)
 .attr("height", h);

//accessor function used by the path generator to produce path data (this works for lines - find another one for archs later)
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
 .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
 .interpolate("linear");

d3.json("http://codepen.io/MadsHolten/pen/RaJGOp.js",function(error, plan) { if (error) return console.error(error);

  //Loop through lines of room 0 (for test purpose)
  var lineArray = [];
  for(i=0;i<plan[0][0].length;i++){
  var pointArray = [];

  //Start point
  var x = (plan[0][0][i].start[0]).toFixed(0);
  var y = (plan[0][0][i].start[1]).toFixed(0);
  var startPoint = {x: x, y: y};
  pointArray.push(startPoint);

  //End point
  var x = (plan[0][0][i].end[0]).toFixed(0);
  var y = (plan[0][0][i].end[1]).toFixed(0);
  var endPoint = {x: x, y: y};
  pointArray.push(endPoint);

  //Push line start and end point to lineArray
  lineArray.push(pointArray);
}

var testdata = JSON.stringify(lineArray);
d3.select("#console").html('testdata = '+testdata+';');

 svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", lineFunction(lineArray))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
});
```

See my full codepen here: http://codepen.io/MadsHolten/pen/mPLzOx?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `lineFunction` expects data of the form `[{x: #, y: #}, {x: #, y: #}]`. Your code gives it an array of this.

In order to split the array into "usable" pieces you have to use the d3 `enter` functionality.

```
  svg.selectAll("path").data(lineArray)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", linefunction)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

This code will:

- Get all paths
- Match the data to all selected paths
- Enter operates on missing elements, i.e. where data exists but nothing was selected
- For the entering objects create a path and set the attributes
- When you use `.attr("d", linefunction)`, it automatically calls `lineFunction` with the data bound to the object

If you replace your append block with this code it will work. That said nothing will display because your coordinates are outside of the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

First, as @JSBob states your data structure is incorrect.  You want an array of points and you have an array of arrays of points.  Instead of doing what he suggest, I would just build the flatter array.

Second, you should be coercing your string x and y values into numbers.

Third, you need to solve you coordinate mapping problem (moving from user space units to pixel space units); this is what [d3.scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) are used for.

Putting all this ideas together:

```js
var w = 1000,
  h = 600;

var svg = d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

//accessor function used by the path generator to produce path data (this works for lines - find another one for archs later)
var xS = d3.scale.linear().range([0,w]),
    yS = d3.scale.linear().range([0,h]);

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xS(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return yS(d.y); })
  .interpolate("linear");

var lineArray = [];

var plan = [[[{"end":[-8486.116239411676,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-2239.281919861382,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-9261.116239411669,12060.110726856617,3199.999999999939],"middle":[-9034.123994831243,12608.118482276192,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"arc","start":[-8486.116239411669,12835.110726856617,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-9261.116239411669,11198.225231380193,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,12060.11072685661,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5826.691683009594,9948.196921016917,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,11198.225231380193,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5826.691683009596,9508.020490004836,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5826.691683009595,9948.196921016919,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5826.6916830096,7618.520490004801,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5826.691683009596,9508.020490004836,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-2239.2819198613906,7618.520490004789,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5826.691683009599,7618.520490004801,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-2239.2819198613815,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-2239.2819198613906,7618.520490004789,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[-2103.7819198613815,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-486.11623941167545,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-2103.781919861391,7618.520490004788,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-2103.781919861382,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[288.88376058833137,7618.520490004782,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-2103.7819198613906,7618.520490004789,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[288.8837605883311,12060.110726856623,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[288.8837605883311,7618.520490004781,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-486.11623941166886,12835.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"middle":[61.89151600790524,12608.118482276192,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"arc","start":[288.88376058833103,12060.110726856617,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[5705.558316990388,7483.020490004815,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,3985.110726856617,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[513.8837605883309,7483.020490004815,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,7483.020490004815,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-2171.531919861391,7483.02049000479,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[513.8837605883309,7483.020490004781,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5826.691683009598,7483.020490004801,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-2171.531919861391,7483.020490004789,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5826.691683009604,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5826.691683009598,7483.020490004801,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-3369.4416830096116,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5826.691683009604,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-3144.441683009611,3985.110726856645,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-3369.441683009612,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[513.8837605883314,3985.110726856634,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-3144.441683009611,3985.1107268566457,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[1938.883760588331,3985.1107268566293,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[513.8837605883311,3985.110726856634,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[5705.558316990389,3985.110726856617,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[1938.883760588331,3985.1107268566293,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[5705.558316990388,3849.610726856618,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,1514.3156084306947,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[2006.6337605883305,3849.6107268566298,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,3849.6107268566175,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[2006.6337605883266,1514.3156084307066,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[2006.6337605883307,3849.6107268566298,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[5705.558316990389,1514.3156084306947,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[2006.6337605883266,1514.3156084307066,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[5705.558316990388,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[2006.633760588323,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[5705.558316990388,1378.815608430694,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[2006.633760588326,1378.8156084307066,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[5705.558316990388,1378.8156084306947,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[2006.6337605883227,-866.9795099951862,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[2006.6337605883266,1378.8156084307066,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[1871.1337605883227,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[581.6337605883233,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[1871.1337605883266,1446.5656084307068,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[1871.1337605883227,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[1871.1337605883307,3849.6107268566293,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[1871.1337605883266,1446.5656084307068,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[581.6337605883309,3849.6107268566343,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[1871.1337605883307,3849.6107268566298,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[581.6337605883233,-866.9795099951866,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[581.6337605883309,3849.6107268566343,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[-3144.4416830096125,-866.9795099951866,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-3144.4416830096125,3849.610726856646,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[446.1337605883232,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-3144.4416830096125,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[446.1337605883308,3849.610726856634,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[446.13376058832324,-866.9795099951864,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-3144.4416830096125,3849.610726856646,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[446.1337605883308,3849.6107268566343,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[-9261.116239411669,4760.11072685661,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,7483.020490004812,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-8486.116239411673,3985.110726856615,3199.999999999939],"middle":[-9034.123994831245,4212.1029714370425,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"arc","start":[-9261.116239411669,4760.110726856617,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009603,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-8486.116239411669,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009598,7483.020490004801,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009604,3985.110726856616,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-9261.116239411669,7483.020490004812,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009598,7483.020490004801,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[-9261.116239411669,7618.520490004812,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,9440.270490004847,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009598,7618.520490004801,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,7618.520490004812,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009595,9440.270490004836,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009599,7618.520490004801,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-9261.116239411669,9440.270490004845,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009595,9440.270490004836,3199.999999999939]}]],[[{"end":[-9261.116239411669,9575.770490004845,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,11054.029143209707,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009594,9575.770490004836,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-9261.116239411669,9575.770490004845,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-5962.191683009594,9853.318799589504,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009595,9575.770490004836,3199.999999999939]},{"end":[-9261.11623941167,11054.029143209707,3199.999999999939],"primitive":"line","start":[-5962.191683009594,9853.318799589504,3199.999999999939]}]]];
  
 
  //Loop through lines of room 0 (for test purpose)  
  for(i=0;i<plan[0][0].length;i++){
    var pointArray = [];
    
    //Start point
    var x = (plan[0][0][i].start[0]).toFixed(0);
    var y = (plan[0][0][i].start[1]).toFixed(0);
    var startPoint = {x: +x, y: +y};
    lineArray.push(startPoint);
    
    //End point
    var x = (plan[0][0][i].end[0]).toFixed(0);
    var y = (plan[0][0][i].end[1]).toFixed(0);
    var endPoint = {x: +x, y: +y};
    lineArray.push(endPoint);
  }
  
 xS.domain(d3.extent(lineArray, function(d){
    return d.x;
})); 
 
 yS.domain(d3.extent(lineArray, function(d){
    return d.y;
  }));
  
  var testdata = JSON.stringify(lineArray);
  d3.select("#console").html('testdata = '+testdata+';');
  
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(lineArray))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="text-center">D3 plan from Flux.io</h2>
  <div id="d3">
  </div>
    <div id="console">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

Now you want to use a [nested selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/):

```
svg.selectAll(".room").data(roomArray)
    .enter()
    .append("g") //<-- each g is a collection of paths that make up the room
    .attr("class", "room")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d){
      return d; //<-- return the array of data for the room
    })
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction)
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZGvdr?editors=1010).

Comment: Thank you both for giving such detailed answers! I ended up doing part of both. I added a point array with all points to get the extends: http://codepen.io/MadsHolten/pen/mPLzOx

Comment: My next problem is that when I am adding the rest of the rooms to the array I get one more level, and I am a bit lost on how I set this up the best way. The idea is that later there will also be added properties to the rooms that should for instance be shown on mouseover. I guess I will need to keep the hierarchy impact then? See this codepen for my attempt: http://codepen.io/MadsHolten/pen/oxyWeW?editors=1010

Comment: @MadsHolten, see updates above.  This is the perfect time to use a *nested selection*.

Comment: thank you so much. It works like a charm :) Now I have a much better understanding of how I can further develop the tool!